# What am I doing wrong in the process of vectorizing the test of whether my geolocation fields are valid?

Tags: python, pandas

I was calling out to a geolocation API and was converting the results to a DataFrame like so:

```
results = geolocator.lookup(ip_list)
```

`results`:

```
[{ 
    query: "0.0.0.0", 
    coordinates: { lat: "0", lon: "0" }
}, ...]
```

So we queried 0.0.0.0 and the API returned "0"s for the lat / long, indicating an IP that obviously cant be geolocated. Weird way to handle things as opposed to a False value or something, but we can work with it.

To DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

But wait, this leads to those "coordinate" fields being dictionaries within the DataFrame, and I may be a Panda beginner but I know I probably want those stored as DataFrames, not dicts, so we can vectorize.

So instead I did:

```
for result in results:
    result["coordinates"] = pd.DataFrame(result["coordinates"], index=[0])
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

Not sure what `index=[0]` does there but without it I get an error, so I did it like that. Stop me here and tell me why I'm wrong if I'm doing this badly so far. I'm new to Python and DataFrames more than 2D are confusing to visualize.

Then I wanted to process over `df` and add a "geolocated" column with `True` or `False` based on a vectorized test, and tried to do that like so:

```
def is_geolocated(coordinate_df):
    # yes the API returned string coords
    lon_zero = np.equal(coordinate_df["lon"], "0") # error here
    lat_zero = np.equal(coordinate_df["lat"], "0")
    return lon_zero & lat_zero

df["geolocated"] = is_mappable(df["coordinates"])
```

But this throws a KeyError "lon".

Am I even on the right track, and if not, how should I set this up?

Answer (score 1):

Generally I would agree with you that a dictionary is a bad way to store latitude/longitude values. This happens due to the way pd.DataFrame() works, as it will pick up on the keys query and coordinates, where the value for the key coordinates is simply a dictionary of the lat/lon values.

You can circumvent the entire problem by, e.g., defining every row as a tuple, and the whole dataframe as a list of these tuples. You can then perform a comparison whether both the lat and lon value are zero, and return this as a new column.

```
import pandas as pd

# Test dataset
results = [{ 
    'query': "0.0.0.0", 
    'coordinates': { 'lat': "0", 'lon': "0" }
},
{ 
    'query': "0.0.0.0", 
    'coordinates': { 'lat': "1", 'lon': "1" }
}]

df = pd.DataFrame([(result['query'], result['coordinates']['lat'], result['coordinates']['lon']) for result in results])
df.columns = ['Query', 'Lat', 'Lon']
df['Geolocated'] = ((df['Lat'] == '0') & (df['Lon'] == '0'))
df.head()

    Query   Lat Lon Geolocated
0   0.0.0.0 0   0   True
1   0.0.0.0 1   1   False
```

In this code I used a list comprehension to build the list of tuples and defined the 'Geolocated' column as a series, which comes from the comparison of the row's Lat and Lon values.